# How can I list Azure FunctionApp functions in a specific deployment slot with Azure CLI

Tags: azure, function, command-line-interface

There is a CLI method to list functions of an Azure FunctionApp ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/function?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-function-list))

`az functionapp function list -g MyResourceGroup -n MyFunctionAppName`

How do I get functions deployed on a specific deployment slot?

For reference, another method - `functionapp function keys list` has a parameter (`-s`) for specifying the slot ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/function/keys?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-function-keys-list)).

Comment: Have you tried any approach/effort? Share the blockers/errors that occurred during the implementation.

Comment: I tried getting it from the functionapp cli, resource cli, resource graph, etc. Doesn't seem like it's possible, I'm doing a workaround in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChatGPT helped me out. The method `az rest` can be used to retrieve the list of functions deployed on a specific deployment slot.

```
az rest --method get --uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTION_ID/resourceGroups/$RESOURCE_GROUP/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$FUNCTION_APP/slots/$DEPLOYMENT_SLOT/functions?api-version=2018-11-01"
```

Works like a charm. The only caveat is that when requesting production slot, you need to omit `slots/$DEPLOYMENT_SLOT/` from the request.

Answer (score 0):

By default `az functionapp list` command does not contain `--slot` parameter to filter the function apps by slots.

Refer this MS document:-
[az functionapp | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-list)

***I added one Function app in **staging slot** and ran the below alternatives to fetch the same deployment slots for specific function app via default hostname.***

As an alternative you can try the below command.

**Code:-**

```
az functionapp show --name MyFunctionapp --resource-group MyResourceGroup --slot staging
```

**Output- Hostname is allocated to staging slot like below:-**

[image]

[image]

To get the specific function app with its slot.
You can also use the command below:-

**Code:-**

```
 az functionapp deployment slot list --name MyFunctionapp --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```

**Output- Hostname is allocated to staging slot like below:-**

[image]

[image]

***I tried running `az functionapp function list` and did not receive any slot property also the command does not contain `--slot` parameter as Deployment slots are added at the Function app level that is app service plan level to manage the application deployment and not its dependent functions like the HTTP or queued triggers at functions level.***

**Refer here :-**
[az functionapp function | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/function?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-function-list)

**Code:-**

```bash
az functionapp function list -g MyResourceGroup -n MyFunctionAppName
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

***Even `az functionapp function show` does not contain `--slot` parameter or slot property in the output.***

**Code:-**

```bash
az functionapp function show -g MyResourceGroup -n MyFunctionAppName --function-name MyFunctionName
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

**References:-**

[az functionapp deployment slot | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/deployment/slot?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-deployment-slot-list)

[az functionapp function | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/function?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-function-show)

[az functionapp function | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/function?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-function-show)

Comment: Thank you! However, this is not what I am trying to achieve. I need to retrieve a list of functions in a FunctionApp. For example, you may have a FunctionApp `UserProfiles` with an HTTP-triggered function `CreateProfile` and a queue-triggered function called `ProcessProfile`. And maybe you just added the `ProcessProfile` function and it's not in production yet, so it will be deployed in certain slots and not in others.

Comment: I tried running `az functionapp function list` and did not receive any slot property also the command does not contain `--slot` parameter as Deployment slots are added at the Function app level that is app service plan level to manage the application deployment and not its dependent functions like the HTTP or queued triggers at functions level. Even `az functionapp function show` does not contain `--slot` parameter or slot property in the output. Check the updated answer

Comment: Refer this Functions deployment slot document for more details : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots